# Apple's Photos app uses UIImagePickerController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, photos

Can any one tell if Apple's Photos app uses UIImagePickerController as the picture shown?  If it uses UIImagePickerController, can you tell where/how to access to individual icon image so that when one taps on it to select, one can impose a tiny checkmark at the corner? ( I don't need to know how to put the check mark).

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Photos app does not use `UIImagePickerController`.  If you need fine grained control, like placing a checkmark over images, you should look into using the AVAssets framework.